# Getting sub-class data(HTML) using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

[image: HTML source]

I'm trying to get title and description data which is shown in the picture using the code below :

```
e = rawData.select("div.progress-2.m-animated.progress-category-item");

      for(Element el : e){
        println(el.text());
      }
```

but it seems there are several other classes which is using the same `div.progress-2.m-animated.progress-category-item` class. because I'm getting other unnecessary datas using this code.
What I want to do is, just like in the image, there is specific id for quickplay/competitive data. And I want to get the only data from it, but I can't figure out how to do such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `bar-text` is a unique class you could do

```
e = rawData.select("div.progress-2.m-animated.progress-category-item > .bar-text");
```

But the easiest thing to do would be to give your div a unique `id`